# *ngFor don't show anything

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a problem on my code. I try to use *ngFor to display some data but I don't know what is wrong with my code. Here is it:
In a src/app/mock-heroes.ts file:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
{ id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
{ id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
{ id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
{ id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
{ id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
{ id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
{ id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
{ id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
{ id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
{ id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

and in my src/heroes/heroes.component.ts file I'd like to display it like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-heroes',
   templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
   hero = HEROES;
   selectedHero: Hero;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
}
```

}

In the src/heroes/heroes.component.html file,

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
   <ul class="heroes">
     <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
     </li>
   </ul>
```

I don't find what's wrong with those codes.

Comment: missing ending `"` here `"let hero of heroes` + where is `heroes` in ts file?

Comment: `hero = HEROES` => `heroes = HEROES;`

Comment: #Silvermind, thank you, it works. I understand right now the principle of the template in angular. #Prashant Pimpale it's already done but I typed this code manually and forget this quote but thank you

Comment: @Tsiresgrammeur, please consider deleting this question as it was a simple typographical issue and would otherwise be closed as **off-topic**

Comment: #SiddAjmera, I'd like but if I delete this, I'll be blocked from asking. That's said in the "confirmation" before deleting.

Answer (score -1):

> heroes.component.ts

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
   heroes : Hero = HEROES;
```

> heroes.component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
```

Answer (score -1):

TS file

```
hero = HEROES;
```

html file

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes>
```

i think it is a wrong typo only you have to make is heroes in ts file the correct ts file have to be like that

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-heroes',
   templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
   heroes = HEROES;
   selectedHero: Hero;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It works by just changing hero = HEROES into heroes = HEROES.